# Shazam detect API throws a HTTP 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to test the Shazam API Detect feature on a mono sample as provided by [this tutorial](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/shazam/tutorials/how-to-use-...%2Fsongs%2Fdetect-endpoint).

My code reads the raw audio file and sends it as base64 plaintext in the body of a POST requests to the Shazam API.

The audio file can be downloaded via [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ldg24swrkhr6l3/AADeEbIiLR4DIR_RpFnphPG4a?dl=0):

```
import requests
import base64

def shazam(payload):
    url = "https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/songs/detect"

    payload = open(payload,"rb").read()
    payload = base64.b64encode(payload)
    payload = str(payload)
    headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "shazam.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key':str(open("./api.txt","r").read().strip()),
    'content-type': "text/plain",
    'accept': "text/plain"
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)

shazam("/home/samples/mono.raw")
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where does it crash? Perhaps you could edit the question and add the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

I'am having problems with this API as well been searching up and down to find a solution :(

Comment: I ended up using another API called AudD. Highly recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

**it work on me**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import base64
import requests
import json


file_path="./test.raw"
url = "https://rapidapi.p.rapidapi.com/songs/detect"
encode_string = base64.b64encode(open(file_path, "rb").read())
payload=encode_string
print(type(payload))

headers = {
    'content-type': "text/plain",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "<<<you key>>>",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "shazam.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
 
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64682491/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.